# GA - Created Custom Report - How to add to other users

Tags: google-analytics, customization

Recently used some custom dimensions to create custom reports. Now i want to add them to the Customisation menu for other users. How can i do this?

Comment: Think i've figured a slightly long method. Custom Reporting -> Overview then go to the "Actions" drop down & click on share. This gives you a link to share with other users. The only problem with this is that it needs to be done for every view the report will be used on.

Comment: You find a similar function in the view settings (shared assets) where you can select multiple custom reports and/or custom segments to share with one url.